# "Bulkify" trigger updating parent object

Tags: trigger, custom-object, bulkification

My trigger currently looks like below:

```
trigger UpdatePEPending on Price_Authorization_Extension__c (before delete) {

//This trigger is to change the PE Pending field on the Price Authorization to false
//if the Price Auth Extension is deleted

    if(System.Trigger.IsDelete){

        Set<Id> paeIds = Trigger.oldMap.keyset();

        list<Price_Authorization_Extension__c> paelist = [SELECT Id, Price_Authorization__r.PE_Pending__c FROM Price_Authorization_Extension__c WHERE Id IN :paeIds];  

        for (Price_Authorization_Extension__c pae :paelist) {
            pae.Price_Authorization__r.PE_Pending__c = False;
            update pae.Price_Authorization__r;
        }
    }
}
```

This works perfectly for one-off situations.  However I have a background apex running which will delete thousands of records at a time and this trigger causes failure.  I tried to bulkify, but the update is not working if I do something like add a list statement and then -->

```
lstToUpdate.add(pae.Price_Authorization__r);
```

I get an error

> Incompatible element type SFDC_Price_Authorization__c for collection
>   of Price_Authorization_Extension__c

I'm an amateur coder and could use some expert help to figure this out.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another way of looking at the problem. It sounds like the aim is to update the parent object when the child object is deleted. The ID of the parent object is available in the trigger without requiring a query, so the trigger can become:

```
trigger UpdatePEPending on Price_Authorization_Extension__c (before delete) {
    Map<Id, Price_Authorization__c> m = new Map<Id, Price_Authorization__c>();
    for (Price_Authorization_Extension__c pae : Trigger.old) {
        Id paId = pae.Price_Authorization__c;
        if (paId != null) {
            m.put(paId, new Price_Authorization__c(
                    Id = paId,
                    PE_Pending__c = false
                    ));
        }
    }
    update m.values();
}
```

This also avoids the risk of multiple updates to the same parent object by using a map keyed by the parent object ID.

Comment: Validation Errors While Saving Record(s)
There were custom validation error(s) encountered while saving the affected record(s). The first validation error encountered was "Apex trigger UpdatePEPending caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: UpdatePEPending: execution of BeforeDelete caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object: Trigger.UpdatePEPending: line 7, column 1".      I'm thinking the record is showing as deleted?

Comment: @ScottPeterson The loop should be over Trigger.old not Trigger.new. Try that change - I'll update the answer. The content of the Trigger context is explained in [Trigger Context Variables](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Since you're updating a related object where there could be a many to one relationship, I recommend you query using a map so you can retrieve and sort the related objects. In doing so, one possibility for coding it would look more like what's below:

```
trigger UpdatePEPending on Price_Authorization_Extension__c (before delete) {

   if(System.Trigger.IsDelete){
       Set<Id> paeIds = Trigger.oldMap.keyset();
       list<Price_Authorization__c>toUpdate = new list<Price_Authorization__c>();

       map<Id,Price_Authorization_Extension__c> paeMap = new map ([SELECT Id, Price_Authorization__r.PE_Pending__c FROM Price_Authorization_Extension__c WHERE Id IN :paeIds]);  

       for (Id pID : paeMap.keyset()) {

          new Price_Authorization_Extension__c pae = paeMap.get(pId); // pulls each Price Auth Ext from map.
          // could add them to a list here, but not needed

          for(Price_Authorization_Extension__c p:pae){

             Price_Authorization__c pac = new Price_Authorization__c(Id=p.Price_Authorization__r);
             // retrieves each related record Id from parent

             pac.PE_Pending__c = False;

             toUpdate.add(pac)
          }

       }

       update toUpdate;

    }

 }
```

Comment: I think you are updating the wrong object. Also the empty check has been redundant for quite a while now.

Comment: Good catch! Will revise code.

Comment: I'm getting the error:     Illegal assignment from Price_Authorization_Extension__c to List<Price_Authorization_Extension__c> at line 15 column 11  which is this line:   paeList = paeMap.get(pId); // pulls map into a list using ID

Comment: That's what happens when you write code on the fly. See revised code above. List isn't needed. Pulls out individual records at that point, which may mean that the loop below it needs to be revised to loop on `Price_Authorization__c` by setting a `list par = pae.Price_Authorization__r` or similar. Yes, that would **have** to be the case.